# Cannot print from Microsoft Office (other programs work fine)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printing

I have a TCP/IP network printer installed on 5 machines in my office.  On 4 of the machines, I can print without problem from any program. On the 5th machine, I can print without problem from any program *except Microsoft Office*.  When I try to print from any of the Office programs, the office shows up in my printer status box with the status "Error - Printing".

Here are all the steps I have tried:

1. Checked my event log, nothing is recorded
2. Followed all the steps from the [MS KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826845)
3. Ran the repair utility on my office installation
4. Reinstalled my printer driver
5. Checked to see if a different driver was available from the manufacturer (there's not)
6. Disabled UAC and ran Word as an adminstrator
7. Tried using a different printer, the other printer worked
8. Tried logging in as a different user, same problem

Comment: Does it work as expected if you log in as a different user?  If you install a different printer (like say a virtual PDF printer) can Office print to it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Different user also has the problem, different printer works fine from Office.

Comment: same version of Word on all computers? whats the printer model? PCL driver or other?

Comment: @Yorik Word 2007 on all machines.  Printer is a Kyocera Mita 3050.  It's actually the fax machine driver for the printer (it lets you print directly to the Kyocera's fax), but on the computer it works like a printer.